# pagination: getting "first" to be the original page when paginate_base is different

Tags: pagination

I'm new to pagination, but not EE so much. I'm working on a site where the front page is basically short news items, preceded by one "featured" item. I'm limiting to 10 news items per page, so I'm using "paginate_base" to indicate that for the following pages, I want a different template to be called (first page is "news" with the "featured" item, and following pages are on the template "continued," without the "featured" item).

It's working fine moving into old entries. But when I want to go back, I want the link for the "first" page to go back to the original "news" template, rather than the "continued" template. To try to be more clear, to go back to the template that has the "featured" item, whereas currently "first" takes me back to the "continued" template with the first news items.

Not sure if I'm explaining this clearly; but any thoughts on if I'm approaching this correctly would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [AB Pagination](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-pagination) add-on that would give you much more control over how it's output, as well as pointing back to your original template page for the first page link.

Answer (score -1):

AB Pagination was a bit more than I needed, so I wound up just adding an artificial "home" button on the pagination for the "continued" pages.